# Unfortunately, (app) has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an app for a course that needs a prototype. The rest of my code is fine, except for this part where I can't switch windows. I hope you can help me because this error is driving me mad. Thanks :)

EDIT: I added the third class

This is my 4th layout

```
package com.example.appxercise_techno;

import com.example.appxercise_techno.activity4;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

   public class activity4 extends activity3 implements OnClickListener{

  Button heart,leg,abs,chest,back;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.sub4);

  heart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.heart);
  leg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.leg);
  abs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.abs);
  chest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.chest);
  back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);

  back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity4.this, activity3.class);
        startActivity(intent);
          }
      });

  heart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity4.this, activity5.class);
          startActivity(intent);
          }
      });

  leg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity4.this, activity6.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

  abs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity4.this, activity7.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

chest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity4.this, activity8.class);
        startActivity(intent);
         }
     });

    }
 }


This is the layout xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/back"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
      android:text="Back" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/large"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
      android:text="Side Quest Trainings"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/abs"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/heart"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/heart"
      android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back"
      android:text="Cores" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/heart"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/large"
      android:layout_below="@+id/large"
      android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
      android:text="Cardio" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/leg"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/chest"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chest"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/abs"
      android:text="Lower" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/chest"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@+id/back"
      android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/back"
      android:text="Upper" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the error

03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192): Process: com.example.appxercise_techno, PID: 1192
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.appxercise_techno/com.example.appxercise_techno.activity4}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at com.example.appxercise_techno.activity2.onCreate(activity2.java:27)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at com.example.appxercise_techno.activity3.onCreate(activity3.java:19)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at com.example.appxercise_techno.activity4.onCreate(activity4.java:16)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
03-07 23:09:21.010: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     ... 11 more

```
This is the third activity

package com.example.appxercise_techno;

import com.example.appxercise_techno.activity3;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;

public class activity3 extends activity2 implements OnClickListener{

TextView out1, out2, out3, out4, out5, out6, big;
Button quest;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.sub3);

    out1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out1);
    out2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out2);
    out3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out3);
    out4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out4);
    out5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out5);
    out6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.out6);
    big = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.big);
    quest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.quest);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String name = extras.getString("name1");
    Double result = extras.getDouble("result");

    big.setText("Your Routine " +name );

    if (result >= 15 && result < 16){

        out1.setText("10 Pushups");
        out2.setText("10 Situps");
        out3.setText("10 Seconds Plank");
        out4.setText("5 Squat Thrusts");
        out5.setText("10 Pullups");
        out6.setText("2 Sets. Rest between sets up to 2 mins.");
    }

    else if (result >= 16 && result < 18.5){

        out1.setText("5 Minutes Running/Walking");
        out2.setText("20 Pushups");
        out3.setText("20 Seconds Plank");
        out4.setText("20 Lunges");
        out5.setText("30 Shadowbox Punches");
        out6.setText("3 Sets. Rest between sets up to 3 mins.");
    }

    else if (result >= 18.5 && result < 25){

        out1.setText("20 Pushups");
        out2.setText("20 Seconds Plank");
        out3.setText("20 Situps");
        out4.setText("12 Flutter Kicks");
        out5.setText("15 Squats");
        out6.setText("5 Sets. Rest between sets up to 2 mins.");
    }

    else if (result >= 25 && result < 30){

        out1.setText("20 Pushups");
        out2.setText("10 Seconds Plank");
        out3.setText("50 Shadowbox Punches");
        out4.setText("60 Seconds One Leg Stand");
        out5.setText("20 Pullups");
        out6.setText("3 Sets. Rest between sets up to 2 mins.");
    }

    else if (result >= 30 && result < 35){

        out1.setText("3 Minutes Sprint");
        out2.setText("10 Jumping Jacks");
        out3.setText("10 Squats");
        out4.setText("5 Second Plank");
        out5.setText("20 Toe Reaches");
        out6.setText("3 Sets. Rest bewteen sets up to 3 mins. ");
    }

    else if (result >= 35){

        out1.setText("3 Minutes Sprint");
        out2.setText("10 Jumping Jacks");
        out3.setText("10 Knee Touches");
        out4.setText("10 Toe Reaches");
        out5.setText("10 Climbers");
        out6.setText("2 Sets. Rest bewteen sets up to 3 mins.");
    }

    quest.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity3.this, activity4.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is activity3 subclassing activity?

Comment: yes it is subclassing.

Comment: Is there any Activity2 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the error line (it should be line 27)

`Intent intent = new Intent(activity4.this, activity3.class);`;

activity3 is extended by activity4. You're sure that activity3 is not abstract? Also, try this, instead of activty4.this, try getContext(). It shouldn't matter but just in case.

Finally, is it crashing on all the buttons or just back?

Comment: I thank you for the answer, but it the error still persists. Maybe is it on the 3rd activity instead of the fourth? Because my code stops as I press a button on the 3rd activity.

Comment: EDIT: I added the third activity

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with `extra` being null.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224608/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-start-activity-componentinfo-java-l).

Add your sub3.xml if problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have problem here

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); // extras is null since you are not setting up bundle there
String name = extras.getString("name1"); // gives NPE
Double result = extras.getDouble("result");
```